# Transfer lines from file.txt in separate files

Tags: python, file-writing

I have this file file.txt which contains 3 lines:

```
hello
there
world
```

I want to send each line from file.txt in separate files like this:

file0 with one line

```
hello
```

file1 with one line

```
there
```

file2 with one line

```
world
```

This is what I've tried by now, but it's not right

```
cnt = 0
with open("file.txt", 'r') as f:
    x = f.readlines()
    with open("file" + str(cnt), "w") as g:
        for i in range(len(x)):
            single_line = x[i]
            g.write(single_line)
        cnt = cnt + 1
```

This gives me only 1 file called file0 with all 3 lines in it.

UPDATE:

```
cnt = 0
with open("./to_split", 'r') as f:
    x = f.readlines()
    for i in range(len(x)):
        with open("file" + str(cnt), "w") as g:
            single_line = x[i]
            g.write(single_line)
        cnt = cnt + 1
```

Comment: Move the for loop outside of the inner `with`

Comment: Oooh, thank you very much!

Comment: what these `for i in range(len(x)):
            single_line = x[i]
            g.write(single_line)` code doing, you can write directly x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cnt = 0
with open("./to_split", 'r') as f:
    x = f.readlines()
    for i in range(len(x)):
        with open("file" + str(cnt), "w") as g:
            single_line = x[i]
            g.write(single_line)
        cnt = cnt + 1
```